# How to get Visual Studio to automatically add a needed Import element in an .aspx file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a class "Message".

In my .aspx file view (ASP.NET MVC), I am typing a line of code and use "Message".

```
<h1>Messages</h1>
<ul>
    <% foreach(Message %>
</ul>
```

I get a helpful bubble that says "The type or namespace Message cannot be found" and gives me a dropdown to add it but merely does this:

```
<h1>Messages</h1>
<ul>
    <% foreach(DataTestProject.Models.Message %>
</ul>
```

What I really want is to have it automatically pop the import statement up at the top like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="DataTestProject.Models" %>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/asp_net_editor.html) will do that for you

It is able to auto-import namespaces and register user controls, in addition to multiple other useful features for ASP.NET developers